# In SQL, how to convert JSON Column string value into int?

Tags: sql, json

I have below sql statement, but I need to store Price in decimal and quantity in integer.
Ho can I do the convert from these Json value string to the right format?
Thanks!

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @json =   
  N'[  
       {  
         "Order": {  
           "Number":"SO43659",  
           "Date":"2023-05-31T00:00:00"  
         },  
         "ItemNumber":"A12345",  
         "Item": {  
           "Price":"24.99",  
           "Quantity":"100,000"  
         }  
       },  
       {  
         "Order": {  
           "Number":"S12345",  
           "Date":"2023-06-01T00:00:00"  
         },  
         "ItemNumber":"AW2312",  
         "Item": {  
           "Price":"2,000.00",  
           "Quantity":"3"  
         }  
      }  
 ]'  
   
SELECT * FROM  
 OPENJSON ( @json )  
WITH (   
              Number   varchar(200) '$.Order.Number' ,  
              Date     datetime     '$.Order.Date',  
              Customer varchar(200) '$.ItemNumber', 
              Quantity int          '$.Item.Quantity',
              Price   decimal(10, 2) '$.Item.Price'
 )
```

I tried CAST but sure what is correct syntax.

Comment: This is simply not valid JSON; `100,000` is not a valid numeric literal (`100000` would be). I suggest you first consult with whatever is generating this pseudo-JSON to see if they/it can't be compelled to do something that will pass an `ISJSON` check (this will not). Having to "correct" it in T-SQL with string manipulation would be quite painful.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT 
     Number,
     Date,     
     Date,   
     Quantity = CONVERT(INT, Quantity),
     Price    
FROM  
OPENJSON ( @json )  
WITH (   
              Number   varchar(200) '$.Order.Number' ,  
              Date     datetime     '$.Order.Date',  
              Date     varchar(200) '$.ItemNumber', 
              Quantity int          '$.Item.Quantity',
              Price   decimal(10, 2) '$.Item.Price'
 )
```

Comment: This doesn't work, and moreover, it *obviously* doesn't work (`Quantity` is already an `INT` if it could be successfully parsed, so converting it again would do nothing).